# SQL row to column transposing

Tags: sql, pivot

I am facing a problem in transposing column to rows,Pivoting seems not to be giving me the result in a way I want to show.

Here is the sample data pattern having n number of rows:

```
Coulmn1      Column2
Customer     C1
Account      A1
Transaction  T1
Transaction  T2
Transaction  T3
Account      A2
Transaction  T11
Transaction  T12
Transaction  T13
Customer     C2
Account      A11
Transaction  T111
Transaction  T112
Transaction  T113
Account      A12
Transaction  T1111
Transaction  T1112
Transaction  T1113
```

I would like to transpose it to below format

```
Customer  Account  Transaction
C1        A1       T1
C1        A1       T2
C1        A1       T3
C1        A2       T11
C1        A2       T12
C1        A2       T13
C2        A11      T111
C2        A11      T112
C2        A11      T113
C2        A12      T1111
C2        A12      T1112
C2        A12      T1113
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If you tried pivot, please post the code.  Also, SQL tables are inherently unordered.  Is there an id or timestamp that determines the rows of these transactions?

Comment: Your data looks hierarchical: Customer - level 0, Account - 1, Trans - 3. Maybe this is what you need instead if available in your version of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the MySQL version of what you want to do.  It uses correlated subqueries to get the customer and account information:

```
select t.Column1,
       (select column2 from t t2 where t2.column1 = 'Customer' and t2.id <= t.id order by t2.id desc limit 1
       ) as customer,
       (select column2 from t t2 where t2.column1 = 'Account' and t2.id <= t.id order by t2.id desc limit 1
       ) as transaction,
from t
where t.column1= 'Transaction'
```

This assumes that you have an id column for ordering the rows.  If not, then you need to figure out a way to get such a column (either an id or a timestamp), because SQL tables are inherently unordered.

The logic would be similar in other databases.  However, instead of `limit 1`, the syntax might be `select top 1` or `where rownum = 1` or `fetch only 1 row`.

Comment: Nitpicking comment: please check your commas.

Comment: I am running this query on sql server with the above data, however the result is just returning 12 rows having - Transaction C1 A1

Comment: I am running it on sql server and the query is select t.col1,
       (select top 1 col2 from  t2 where t2.col1 = 'Customer' and t2.id <= t.id order by t2.id 
       ) as customer,
       (select top 1 col2 from  t2 where t2.col1 = 'Account' and t2.id <= t.id order by t2.id 
       ) as [transaction]
from  t
where t.col1= 'Transaction'

Comment: @user2123852 . . . Sorry about that.  I left out the `desc` in the `order by`.

Comment: thank you, it looks better now still I can only see : Transaction C1 A1, Transaction C1 A2 However I am expecting to see transaction as well T1, T2 etc